# $search" had the wrong type. Expected string, found null MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple app that uses React on the front end and Node.js on the backend. What I am trying to achieve is get the input value of a search field and query the MongoDB database using that input value. Currently when I send the value of the input to my /search endpoint I get this error:

`MongoError: "$search" had the wrong type. Expected string, found null`
Why is the query null when I am sending it and how can I send it rigth? Here is my input:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Search extends Component {


    getSearchQuery = () => {

        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;

        axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
            queryString: queryString,
        });

        console.log(queryString)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-input"
                />
                <button type="submit" onClick={this.getSearchQuery}></button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

```
// Requiring the dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;
const itemRoutes = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(BASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', function () {
  console.log('Connection to MongoDB established succesfully!');
});

let collection = connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test");
collection.createIndex(
  {
    postContent: 'text',
    title: 'text'
  }
);

itemRoutes.route('/search').post(async (req, res) => {
  connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test").createIndex({ postContent: "text" })
  let result = await connection.collection("posts_with_tags_test").find({
    $text: {
      $search: req.body.queryString
    }
  }).toArray();
  res.send(result);
});

app.use('/', itemRoutes);
app.use('/comments', itemRoutes);
app.use('/search', itemRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Server is running on' + ' ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: 1. You posted an object with the key `queryString`, but accessed `req.body.query`. 2 You also kind of do a redundant work by using a form submission and axios at the same time.

Comment: how can I post the value correctly? If I remove the queryString and just use req.body,query I still get the same error

Comment: Your second parameter of `axios` is an object, so it's a json that can be accessed at `req.body`. If you have a key `queryString`, then it would be at `req.body.queryString`

Comment: I suspect you would get double requests as well because you also have a form submission

Comment: I got rid of the form, using axios the way that I have described and accessing ```req.body.queryString``` still gives me the samer error

Comment: Could you perhaps update what you have tried so far?

Comment: yes, I updated my question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214851/discussion-between-thammada-and-mahma-deva).